# Assist with javascript functions being contained within a loop (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, loops

I am working on a project where I have divisions stored in mysql database with the "division id" and the "division name";

what I want to have is so that i use php to do a "while" loop and go through all the divisions;

then for each division it creates a button which will trigger a javascript function…

I have done a lot of testing on this so I know certain parts are working…; here is my code:

```
<p id="id57512">How are you?</p>

<script>
var g_myobj = {};
</script>

<?php

$result_g1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM divisions");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_g1, MYSQL_BOTH))
{
$div_id=$row[div_id];
$div_name=$row[div_name];

$button_id="b";
$button_id.=$div_id;

$function_id="f";
$function_id.=$div_id;

?>

<button id=<?php echo $button_id; ?>><?php echo $div_name; ?></button>

<script>
var f_id='<?php echo $function_id; ?>';
var b_id='<?php echo $button_id; ?>';
var div_id='<?php echo $div_id; ?>';

var newFieldName = f_id;
var newFieldValue = function()    {document.getElementById("id57512").firstChild.nodeValue=gman_code1(div_id);};
g_myobj[newFieldName] = newFieldValue;


var gman_code1 = function(number) {
var result1 = number*2;
console.log(result1);
return result1;//add return statement
}

//define the behavior

document.getElementById(b_id).addEventListener("click", g_myobj[f_id] , false);

</script>

<?php
}
```

the function names need to be a variable; but I figured out how to do that by making it an object; and so can access the different functions that way…

I basically tested this all when it was not in a loop; where I manually had it do everything  twice (even creating the functions in the object) and it all worked fine…

basically when you click on a button it is supposed to send a number to that "p" container and multiply it by 2

when I did it manually and not in loop i just had it create the object g_myobj first and then just started adding items to the object…

but now that i am doing this in a loop - I felt I could not have the statement that creates the empty object in the loop or it would just keep recreating it; so I went above the loop and had the object created there in its own "script" tags all by itself…

that part may be a problem with this, not sure at all…

another potential problem is that I am not sure if I can do all this in a loop like this

it is a "php loop" and so maybe this just all cannot be done in a loop like that…

What is going on is the first button works but none of the others do…

So, I am hoping someone can advise me on what I am doing wrong on this…

Thanks so much...

Comment: Store the required properties as data attributes on the buttons. And by using event delegation in JavaScript you only need one function that contains the logic you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is send a number to `<p>` and multiply it by 2, see this one liner function. I assume you are trying to accomplish more than just the multiplying thing otherwise you probably would have just done a simple function like below...

Also, I'm sure you will get lots of comments on it, but you should not be using the `mysql_` functions anymore. They are both deprecated and potentially unsafe. You should use `mysqli` or `PDO` prepared statements.

On your button, you should probably put quotes around the `id="yadayada"` instead of `id=yadayada`. jQuery may be a good option for your js to handle functions or what-have-you.

```
<p id="id57512">How are you?</p>
<?php

    $result_g1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM divisions");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_g1, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
            $div_id         =   $row[div_id];
            $div_name       =   $row[div_name];

            $button_id      =   "b$div_id";
            $function_id    =   "f$div_id"; ?>

    <button id="<?php echo $button_id; ?>" onClick="MyRadFunction('<?php echo $div_id; ?>')">

<?php echo $div_name; ?></button>

<?php   } ?>

<script>

     function MyRadFunction(DivId) {
            $("#id57512").html(DivId*2);
        //  var NewNum  =   $("#id57512").text();
        }
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello Rasclatt:  I tried this and it worked partially; for some reason each button does not work until you have clicked on it at least once; but if you click on it a second time then they work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Hello Rasclatt: It looks like you got my message and edited this - I just tried it and it works great now!  I am sorry I did not see this sooner, I was not paying very close attention.  And I wish I could make the person who down voted this take it back.  Oh well.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I don't think I can do anything, at least me marking this as the right answer should help a little… :)

Comment: I just tried to "vote up" on it but it says to do that I need reputation of 15 and I only have 11… but thanks so much...

Comment: Hey if you went back and up-voted me, (I noticed u have 18 rep now) I appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

When rendering your button, you should wrap the `id` in quotes, e.g.

`<button id='<?php echo $button_id; ?>'><?php echo $div_name; ?></button>`